# ArcMap modelbuilder CalculateValue precondition not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, precondition

I am using ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10, this is my model:
[image]

Cell Statistics shall be calculated for only those rasters dating in summer months (April - October), input raster name format is yYYYYmMM, e.g. y2007m10. Therefore my precondition as boolean value: 
[image: Wert berechnen = Calculate value]

The model is working but calculates cell statistics for all input rasters, not only for the summer months. Probably my code is incorrect, or are the elements wrongly ordered?

Comment: Try changing the summer and winter to true and false. I believe the boolean date type is expecting one of these two outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the classic mistake with the iterator and collects tool, this needs to be in a sub-model as shown below:

[image: Models]

Note *Raster* and *output_value* are preconditions. The code in the calculate value tool is different too as Lou suggested:

[image: Calculate Value code]